# CGAL fails with insertion operation in 2D arrangements

Tags: mesh, cgal

When I switched to CGAL 4.12-beta2 from CGAL-4.4, I get following exception thrown

```
Exception: CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: (m_traits.compare_y_at_x_2_object()(p, cv) == EQUAL) && compare_xy(cv.left(), p) == SMALLER && compare_xy(cv.right(), p) == LARGER
File: D:\PE\PE_Software\3rdParty\CGAL\CGAL-4.12-beta2\include\CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h
Line: 714
```

Any help appreciated

Below is the piece test function that can reproduce this bug. This case has 4 lines with one line intersecting two of them.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT                                        Number_type;

typedef CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel>              Traits;
typedef Traits::Point_2                                 Point;
typedef Traits::X_monotone_curve_2                      Segment;

typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits>                     Arrangement;
typedef Arrangement::Vertex_handle                      Vertex_handle;
typedef Arrangement::Halfedge_handle                    Halfedge_handle;
typedef Arrangement::Face_handle                        Face_handle;
typedef Arrangement::Vertex_const_handle                Vertex_const_handle;
typedef Arrangement::Halfedge_const_handle              Halfedge_const_handle;


typedef CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits, int>
    Data_traits;
typedef Data_traits::Curve_2                               Numbered_segment;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Data_traits>                   Numbered_arr;

Numbered_arr   arr;

insert(arr, Numbered_segment(Segment(Point(1.6831200000000E+02,-1.3992000000000E+01), Point(    1.2253100000000E+02,    -2.0889000000000E+01)), 6));
insert(arr, Numbered_segment(Segment(Point(1.6490200000000E+02, 1.0314000000000E+01), Point(    1.0342400000000E+02,    4.2850000000000E+00)), 11));
insert(arr, Numbered_segment(Segment(Point(1.7217000000000E+02,-3.2611000000000E+01), Point(    9.9756000000000E+01,    -4.3728000000000E+01)), 16));
insert(arr, Numbered_segment(Segment(Point(1.4197300000000E+02, 5.4490000000000E+00), Point(    1.4887000000000E+02,    -4.0331000000000E+01)), 51));
```

Comment: What if you switch from `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` to `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`?

Comment: If I try with it, it is working without assertions.

Comment: But that would mean 4.12 does not have backward compatibility with 4.4 and makes difficult for big applications using CGAL like mine

Comment: Even with 4.4 you should have been using a kernel with exact constructions. I was luckily working but could have failed as well.

Comment: That's strange. Because I have been using this model for many years for many different configurations without any fail.

Comment: A possible explanation is that you were using the code compiled in release mode, and in this case the assertions are suppressed. Nevertheless, as sloriot says, you should use exact constructions, cause the assertion occurs inside the split function-object (which constructs new geometric objects).

Comment: The case I gave here works perfectly with CGAL 4.4 even under debug mode. Also to make things complicated seems like constrained Delauny triangulation can not work with exact construction kernel with 4.12